# How to satisfy Java compiler's unchecked warning for setting a SimpleObjectProperty

Tags: java, object-property

I have this class:

```
package mydate;

import java.util.Date;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class MyDate {
    private final ObjectProperty<Date> theDate;

    public MyDate(Date d) { theDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(d); }

    public ObjectProperty theDateProperty() { return theDate; }

    public Date getTheDate() { return (Date)theDateProperty().get(); }
    //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setTheDate(Date value) { theDateProperty().set(value); }
}
```

This is a simple app that uses it:

```
package unchecked;
import java.util.Date;
import mydate.*;

public class Unchecked {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyDate myDate = new MyDate(new Date(0));
        System.out.println(myDate.getTheDate().toString());
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to satisfy the compiler about setTheDate.  I can suppress the unchecked warning, but I'd like to know if there is something reasonable I can do in using ObjectProperty and SimpleObjectProperty to avoid the unchecked.  I've tried a few things and googling comes close but not quite close enough for me to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectProperty<Date>` is a parametrized type. You declared your instance variable type properly (`ObjectProperty<Date>`), but you didn't declare type parameter in parametized type returned from method `theDateProperty()`. This method should be declared this way:

`public ObjectProperty<Date> theDateProperty()`

After that, all warnings are gone.

Comment: Thank you, ctomek.  I wish I had enough reputation to upcount your answer today.

Comment: @mrmsbarnes What you can do is to accept that answer by clicking on the mark under votes count. ; )